Tiling of a sphere.
Consider a tiling of a sphere by quadrilateral tiles. View the tiling as the embedding of a planar graph $\Gamma$ on the surface of a sphere.
Say you had a homomorphism $\phi: \pi_1 (\Gamma) \to G$ where G is some non-abelian group such that $\phi$ evaluates to 1 on the boundary of all tiles but one (where the boundary of a tile is just the boundary of the complement of  a tile in $S^2$). Would $\phi$ evaluate to 1 on the remaining tile as well?
Instinct tells me yes and so I tried a proof by induction on the number of generators of $\pi_1 (\Gamma)$ but that didn't yield much. Any comments on this problem would be very helpful.

Since the boundary of that tile is also boundary of $S^2$ minus that tile, you can shrink it on that side, so I think the boundary of that tile should also be mapped to $1$.

Your question is very unclear. $\phi$ has to be a function on (homotopy equivalence classes of)  loops in the graph $\Gamma$. You haven't made it clear what that function is.

I feel like the answer should be "yes" if you replace $\pi_1$ with $H_1$, but probably "no" for fundamental groups. Your answer isn't even well-posed for $\pi_1$, as a fundamental group needs a basepoint which isn't going to intersect every boundary, so the homotopy class of a boundary isn't well defined as it depends on the path you take from the basepoint to that boundary.
